# wp_login and is_user_logged_in

Tags: wordpress

I am developing an extension for a plugin and would like to run some code after every time a user logs in. Because I extend a plugin, I wanted to use the already written functions, which inside use `is_user_logged_in()` calls. If I register for the wp_login action and run `is_user_logged_in` in my action hook it returns false, which sounds really weird. 
Code I was running:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'exhib_persist_cookies_after_login');

/*
* This method will persist the  favorite posts from the cookies just after someone logs      in.
*/

function exhib_persist_cookies_after_login() {
  //Check if all the required functions are available
  if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
    error_log("persist: USER LOGGED IN"); 
  }
  else {
    error_log("persist: USER NOT LOGGED IN");
  }
}
```

And in the log I see *USER NOT LOGGED IN*.

Anyone has a clue why is it happening? I thought `is_user_logged_in` is checking for the auth cookie, which is according to the doc is already set before `wp_login` is getting called.

Or anyone has an another idea what action should I register, which only fires once a user logged in and the `is_user_logged_in` returns there true?

Comment: How is that `Because I extend a plugin`? Where is this main plugin? I suppose you're only showing the extension...

Comment: I downloaded this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/ and editing the wp-favorite-posts/wp-favorite-posts.php file. I just added the code above to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you even look at *why* the modification isn't working, you should think about changing *how* you're modifying the plugin. Directly modifying a plugin is dangerous. It breaks the upgrade path preventing you from applying upgrades in the future which could resolve critical issues with the plugin itself. The same functionality could be achieved by creating a simple plugin that contains nothing but the code you want to run.